# select_max not working properly.. it always results to 1

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is in my model.. it says  Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to int.. the problem is in the select_max('id');
and it always result to 1. Please help i'm new to codeigniter

```
public function addEstablishment()
{
   $capacity = $this->input->post('capacity');

   $name = $this->input->post('name');
   $curfew = $this->input->post('curfew');
   $price = $this->input->post('price');
   $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
   $type = $this->input->post('type');

   $this->db->select_max('id');
   $result = $this->db->get('establishment');
   $query = $result + 1;


   $owner = $this->session->userdata('id');

   $data = array(
      'id' =>  $query,
      'name' => $name ,
      'capacity' => $capacity ,
      'curfew' => $curfew ,
      'gender' => $gender ,
      'type' => $type , 
      'owner' => $owner
    );

   if($this->db->insert('establishment', $data))
   {
      echo "Successfully added";
   } 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666446/select-max-query-returns-only-1-variable-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

You have not get `max ID` in result, please try this way

change

```
$this->db->select_max('id');
$result = $this->db->get('establishment');
```

to

```
$this->db->select_max('id');
$result = $this->db->get('establishment')->row()->id;
```